# What do the symbols -> achieve in a line of code?

Tags: c, pointers, fifo

The symbols -> appear in a line of code that I am trying to understand and someone told me it is a pointer.

```
     *data = (uint8_t)base->FIFORD;
```

My interpretation is that the 8 bit integer pointer base points to a register called FIFORD. The value in FIFORD is then assigned to the pointer data. Is this correct?

BONUS: If I wanted to store the values from FIFORD in a buffer to print, what would I need to do?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `base` is a pointer to a datastructure. A data structure just means that it's just a group of variables. They are stored as a group because they are strongly related. Somewhere else in your code `base` is created as a data structure of a type "X". Even before that there will be a definition of how this type should look (at the very least this definition will say that X contains a variable always called `FIFORD`).
  ***We know that `base` is a pointer because of the arrow. If it would be the data structure itself the code would become `*data = (uint8_t) base.FIFORD;`***
- `FIFORD` is a variable in the data structure that `base` points to. The code does not mention what the the type is, but what what we do know is that it's probably a number.
- We know that it's probably a number because we use `(uint8_t)` to change it's type to `uint8_t` (which is usually used to save natural numbers)
- `data` is pointer. We know this because of the `*`-sign. `*data =` means 'the place in memory that `data` points to should be set to...`

So the full meaning of this line:
Don't change the place `data` points to, but instead change the value at that spot to a `uint_8t` conversion of the value of the `FIFORD` variable in the datastructure that is saved at the spot where `base` points to.

PS: The original `FIFORD` never changes.

About the "bonus"-question, I don't really understand your question since the value is already stored in memory. (Twice even after this line). You can just use printf-funtion to print it.
Something like `printf("Current value of data: %ui\n", *data);` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For the bonus question, I was trying to find a way to use UART communication protocols to send keyboard input to a terminal window without the use of printf. I am using MCUXpresso IDE and using printf is printing statements in the console, but not the terminal window. I ended up calling USART_WriteBlocking function provided by the IDE which printed it just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, "base" is a pointer to a structure.

There are two ways you can access variables in a structure with its pointer (base):

1. `(*base).FIFORD`
2. `base -> FIFORD`

Both do the same thing

In this case, the FIFORD variable in the struct is extracted, casted to uint8_t and assigned to a, hopefully (Too little context to say), uint8_t pointer called data.